# Removing child table when appending another

Tags: javascript

Hi i am new to javascript and I am using a select element to create a table based on an array of dictionaries. I have the select element acting as a filter for the values. My problem is that when i change the value of the select element and it creates the table I want it to remove the previous table it appended so that It doesnt form a long list of tables. My on change code is as follows:

```
const filteredTable = document.getElementById("candidates_example");
const newFilteredTable = filteredTable.cloneNode(true);

removeRowsFromTable(newFilteredTable);
const filteredTbody = newFilteredTable.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

const filterSelection = document.getElementById("filterSelect").value;
const selectFilter = filterCandidateBySkill(newCandidates, filterSelection)
addCandidatesToTable(filteredTbody,selectFilter);

document.body.appendChild(newFilteredTable);
```

I have tried googling the question I have but i do not know enough about javascript terminologies to know what the question is I need to ask. Thanks for any guidance offered.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the previous table with the new one using [replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild):

> replacedNode = parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);

In your case, that would be :

```
document.body.replaceChild(newFilteredTable, filteredTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead on append use .html() for jquery or document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = tableVaiable;

Answer (score 0):

You can use the functionality of .replaceWith() jQuery function.
[.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)